# How can I add a sound effect to my buttons?

Tags: html, button, audio, click, effect

I want to make a sound effect for my buttons, so when the user clicks it, it goes 'ding'. I have a 1.6 second MP3 file I would like to play upon each click.

I have not started using java-script but everywhere I look, I need java-script to run this. I thought it might be able to be set up like background music.

I figure adding an example of my own code would not help here. I think an example of this will do, and I would be able to understand it reasonable clearly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not very hard. Here is a minimal example:

*(Enjoy the Free Software Song)*

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button'),
    audio = null;

button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

function handler() {
  audio = new Audio('https://www.gnu.org/music/FreeSWSong.ogg');
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<button>Play</button>
```

Comment: That sound is the longest "ding" I've ever heard.